# Sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n+2}{n(n+1)2^{n+1}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm given the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n+2}{n(n+1)2^{n+1}}$$

I've tried splitting up the fractions to use the telescoping effect, but no terms seem to cancel out. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 2):

The given expression can be written as 
$$\frac{n+2}{n(n+1)2^{n+1}} = \frac{1}{n2^n} - \frac{1}{(n+1)2^{n+1}}$$ which is the desired telescopic sum

Comment: Thank you, that is what I was looking for. Could you please explain how you got that?

Comment: Ofcourse! We can write the numerator as $2(n+1)-n$ which can then be factorised to get the telescopic above

Answer (score 1):

Hint

Let $$\dfrac{n+2}{n(n+1)2^{n+1}}=f(n+1)-f(n)$$

where $f(m)=\dfrac{a_0+a_1m+a_2m^2+\cdots}{m2^m}$

$$\dfrac{n+2}{n(n+1)2^{n+1}}= \dfrac{n(a_0+a_1(n+1)+a_2(n+1)^2+\cdots)-2(n+1)(a_0+a_1n+a_2n^2+\cdots)}{n(n+1)2^{n+1}} $$

$$\implies n+2=n(a_0+a_1(n+1)+a_2(n+1)^2+\cdots)-2(n+1)(a_0+a_1n+a_2n^2+\cdots)$$

Compare the coefficients of $n^2$ and above to find $a_r=0\forall r\ge1$

$$\implies n+2=na_0-2(n+1)a_0=-2a_0-na_0$$

$$\implies a_0=-1$$